# How do I make my distro's libQtCore v5.10.1 available, when the application's shipped v5.6 is in use?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, qt

1) When I start Understand from the command line, I see the following. All is OK. :

```
[me@box1 ~]# understand
```

2) Under the "Getting Started" heading, on the "Getting Started"-tab :

when I click on any of the links "Understand Help...", "Understand FAQ...", "Understand Perl API Help...", "Understand Python API Help...", and "SciTools Support...",
and also on the same links in the "Help"-menu,
then the following errors are added to the terminal window and nothing happens :

```
[me@box1 4.4.19 vpn-client]# understand
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by kde-open5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5KIOWidgets.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5KIOCore.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5I18n.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5CoreAddons.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5JobWidgets.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5Service.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5Completion.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5IconThemes.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5WindowSystem.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5ConfigWidgets.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5WidgetsAddons.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5ConfigGui.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5ConfigCore.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libQt5DBus.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5DBusAddons.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5Auth.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libQt5X11Extras.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libQt5Svg.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5Archive.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5ItemViews.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5Codecs.so.5)
kde-open5: /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/lib/libKF5GuiAddons.so.5)
```

3) `qmake` informs me that Qt v5.10.1 is installed by my distro (Arch Linux) :

```
[me@box1 ~]# qmake -version
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.10.1 in /usr/lib
```

4) `readelf` informs me (and confirms `qmake`'s output) that my distro installed Qt Core v5.10.1 :

```
[me@box1 ~]# readelf -V /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.10.1 | grep -ie 'Qt_5\.'
  d7c:   9h(Qt_5.5)        bh(Qt_5.7)        e (Qt_5.10)       3 (Qt_5)       
  d80:   5h(Qt_5.1)        ch(Qt_5.8)        7h(Qt_5.3)        8h(Qt_5.4)     
  d84:   ah(Qt_5.6)        dh(Qt_5.9)        4h(Qt_5.0)        6h(Qt_5.2)     
  149c:   3 (Qt_5)          e (Qt_5.10)       3 (Qt_5)          2 (Qt_5_PRIVATE_API)   
  14c0:   3 (Qt_5)          4 (Qt_5.0)        3 (Qt_5)          3 (Qt_5)       
  14c4:   3 (Qt_5)          3 (Qt_5)          5 (Qt_5.1)        3 (Qt_5)       
  14c8:   6 (Qt_5.2)        2 (Qt_5_PRIVATE_API)      7 (Qt_5.3)        3 (Qt_5)       
  14cc:   8 (Qt_5.4)        3 (Qt_5)          3 (Qt_5)          3 (Qt_5)       
  14d0:   3 (Qt_5)          3 (Qt_5)          9 (Qt_5.5)        3 (Qt_5)       
  14d4:   3 (Qt_5)          a (Qt_5.6)        3 (Qt_5)          3 (Qt_5)       
  14d8:   3 (Qt_5)          2 (Qt_5_PRIVATE_API)      b (Qt_5.7)        3 (Qt_5)       
  14dc:   2 (Qt_5_PRIVATE_API)      3 (Qt_5)          c (Qt_5.8)        3 (Qt_5)       
  14e0:   3 (Qt_5)          d (Qt_5.9)        3 (Qt_5)          2 (Qt_5_PRIVATE_API)   
  0x0054: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 4  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.0
  0x0078: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 5  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.1
  0x0094: Parent 1: Qt_5.0
  0x009c: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 6  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.2
  0x00b8: Parent 1: Qt_5.1
  0x00c0: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 7  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.3
  0x00dc: Parent 1: Qt_5.2
  0x00e4: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 8  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.4
  0x0100: Parent 1: Qt_5.3
  0x0108: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 9  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.5
  0x0124: Parent 1: Qt_5.4
  0x012c: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 10  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.6
  0x0148: Parent 1: Qt_5.5
  0x0150: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 11  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.7
  0x016c: Parent 1: Qt_5.6
  0x0174: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 12  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.8
  0x0190: Parent 1: Qt_5.7
  0x0198: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 13  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.9
  0x01b4: Parent 1: Qt_5.8
  0x01bc: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 14  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.10
  0x01d8: Parent 1: Qt_5.9
```

5) `readelf` informs me that Understand is shipped with Qt v5.6 :

```
[me@box1 ~]# readelf -V /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5 | grep -ie 'Qt_5\.'
  9e8:   3 (Qt_5)          3 (Qt_5)          4 (Qt_5.0)        2 (Qt_5_PRIVATE_API)   
  9ec:   3 (Qt_5)          3 (Qt_5)          5 (Qt_5.1)        3 (Qt_5)       
  9f0:   6 (Qt_5.2)        3 (Qt_5)          2 (Qt_5_PRIVATE_API)      3 (Qt_5)       
  9f4:   2 (Qt_5_PRIVATE_API)      7 (Qt_5.3)        3 (Qt_5)          8 (Qt_5.4)     
  9f8:   3 (Qt_5)          3 (Qt_5)          9 (Qt_5.5)        3 (Qt_5)       
  9fc:   3 (Qt_5)          3 (Qt_5)          a (Qt_5.6)        2 (Qt_5_PRIVATE_API)   
  d90:   3 (Qt_5)          5h(Qt_5.1)        4h(Qt_5.0)        a (Qt_5.6)     
  d94:   8h(Qt_5.4)        9h(Qt_5.5)        6h(Qt_5.2)        7h(Qt_5.3)     
  0x0054: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 4  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.0
  0x0078: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 5  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.1
  0x0094: Parent 1: Qt_5.0
  0x009c: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 6  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.2
  0x00b8: Parent 1: Qt_5.1
  0x00c0: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 7  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.3
  0x00dc: Parent 1: Qt_5.2
  0x00e4: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 8  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.4
  0x0100: Parent 1: Qt_5.3
  0x0108: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 9  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.5
  0x0124: Parent 1: Qt_5.4
  0x012c: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 10  Cnt: 2  Name: Qt_5.6
  0x0148: Parent 1: Qt_5.5
```

6) `ldd` informs me that Understand will use its shipped version of Qt :

```
[me@box1 ~]# ldd /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/understand.bin | grep -ie 'scitools'
        libQt5Concurrent.so.5 => /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Concurrent.so.5 (0x00007f0a63b77000)
        libQt5Sql.so.5 => /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f0a63af9000)
        libQt5Network.so.5 => /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f0a624dd000)
        libQt5Xml.so.5 => /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Xml.so.5 (0x00007f0a63abd000)
        libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007f0a63a4d000)
        libastyle.so => /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libastyle.so (0x00007f0a6229a000)
        libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f0a61c12000)
        libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f0a61732000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f0a6117a000)
```

7) The Bash script `understand` that starts `understand.bin` contains the following :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
scriptdir=`dirname $0`
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$scriptdir
unset QT_PLUGIN_PATH
$0.bin "$@"
```

8) Copying the `understand` script, and adding the line `echo "\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH after === $LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` revealed that it was set to :

```
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH after === /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64
```

9) Obviously the libraries that throw the error are looking for a Qt v5.10 Core library. But are finding the Qt v5.6 Core library that was shipped with Understand.

So I added a symlink to the understand directory with :

```
[me@box1 ~]# ln -sf /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.10.1 /home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5.10
```

But that didn't change a thing.

I then proceeded to change the copy of the "understand" Bash script (`understand-test`) and changed the line `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$scriptdir` into `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$scriptdir:/usr/lib`. But that also didn't change a thing.

**While** `/home/me/bin/scitools/bin/linux64/libQt5Core.so.5` **(v5.6) is in use, what can I do to make libraries like** `/usr/lib/libKF5KIOWidgets.so.5`**,** `/usr/lib/libKF5KIOCore.so.5`**, etc find and use v5.10.1** `/usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.10.1` **?**

Comment: Why not just remove the 5.6 libs?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Because it's not my copy of Understand. The company that I'm currently contracting with, allows me to telecommute and install it on my own desktop for the duration of the contract. I'm not allowed to make changes. Copying the Bash script and making a change to it, is already a bit of a grey area I guess.

Comment: The Enter-key posts here apparently.
Your comment spurred me to make a further change to the copied Bash script. I changed line `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$scriptdir` into `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib`. And that did the trick. Understand now runs on QT 5.10.1 and all the links open up and work.

I'm waiting for approval now to make the change.
Thanks for your suggestion. :)

Comment: `/usr/lib` is already in the loader search path, so you should be able to remove the variable completely.

Comment: You're right again. Just checked.  I updated the email with my request. That I will comment out that specific line. Thanks!
Are Qt libraries backward compatible by default, and the reason why `readelf` shows the older versions?

Comment: Generally the way it works is that minor versions of libraries are supposed to be backward-compatible, and major versions may break the API.

Comment: OK thanks for clearing that up. I also just received a go ahead response from the company. So I'm good to go. Thanks for your help.
How do I mark your comment as the accepted answer?

Comment: You don't; let me write something up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally libraries are backwards-compatible across minor versions so you should be able to use the system Qt5 instead of the supplied. You can do this by removing the 5.6 library files, or if those are the only library files of import in that directory then you can omit `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` entirely.